# Google Chrome показывает уведомление «xdg-open» при открытии через закладки ссылки с портом 8080

Tags: apache, google-chrome, браузер

- Порт `80` слушает NGINX, `8080` — Apache.
- В закладках у меня две ссылки: http://test.loc и http://test.loc:8080.
- Открываю **через закладки** http://test.loc —­ всё норм.
- Открываю **через закладки** http://test.loc:8080 — показывает уведомление `xdg-open`:

[image: Скриншот 1]
[image: Скриншот 2]

- Если ввожу адрес http://test.loc:8080 вручную, то ссылка открывается без уведомления `xdg-open`.
- В Firefox 88.0, открывается в обоих (через закладки или вручную) случаях нормально.

---

- Если в уведомлении `xdg-open` нажать `Cancel`, то уведомление исчезает, но страница просто белая остаётся; если `Open xdg-open`, то вкладка закрывается и ничего не происходит.
- Если после нажатия `Cancel` кликнуть на `Reload this page`, то опять появляется уведомление `xdg-open`.

---

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

---

**Как убрать это уведомление и почему оно появляется?**

Comment: Он считает, что test.loc - это какой-то файл. Вам надо сменить имя вашего виртуального хоста.

Comment: @gbg, нет, изменил на .local — то же самое.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что сначало починилось, а потом опять поломалось?

Comment: @gbg, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1288833/201026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что если мы добавляем в закладки ссылку без указания протокола, например `example.com`, то Google Chrome автоматически переписывает её в `http://example.com/`. Однако, если мы укажем порт, например `example.com:8080`, то он не добавит протокол. Соответственно, ссылка будет иметь вид `example.com:8080` (то есть как добавляем, так и добавляется) и при открытии (именно через **Bookmark bar**, НЕ через **Bookmark manager**), Google Chrome не понимает по какому протоколу её открывать и предлагает открыть через `xdg-open`.

**UPDATE (2021-06-02)**

Если добавлять закладку с портом без указания протокола (`example.com:8080`) НЕ через **Bookmark manager**, **Bookmark bar**, то Google Chrome добавит протокол и слэш в конце (поэтому не будет вызываться `xdg-open`).